# VBA Office 2010 Outlook issues

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

I have just gotten an upgrade from our IT guy on to Office 2010 where I work so that I could check the functonality of VBA scripts I had written in office. The only one's ive come across so far are in Outlook 2010 and are shown below. I've marked the lines with 3 *'s at each end which are not working. Can anybody advise? I cannot find any solutions online
 (the ....'s in the address are to remove the file path on here only)

```
Sub UpdatedQMISReply()

Location = InputBox("Please enter the UNC (http://) path for the new file", "UNC location")
Location2 = InputBox("Please enter the QMIS path for the new file", "UNC location")

'
' UpdatedQMISReply Macro
' Insert QMIS Document Updated text
'
    ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeText Text:="Dear User,"
    ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
    ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
    ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeText Text:="This email is to confirm that your recent file update request to QMIS has now been completed. I have uploaded all the requested files and have saved a copy into the archive folder "
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeText Text:="(if an old file existed)."
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeText Text:="The location on QMIS for the uploaded document is: "


***ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=Location, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Location2***


ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeText Text:="If your update was concerning a Health & Safety Document such as a Risk Assessment, or Safe System of Work, then please note that the naming convention for these documents is changing, also the location of the document may change without prior warning as the QMIS infrastructure is modified."
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeText Text:="Should you have any further queries regarding this update then please do not hesitate to contact me"
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.TypeText Text:="Regards"
End Sub
Sub DocumentRenewalNeeded()
'
' QMIS.DocumentRenewalNeeded Macro
' Macro created 26/10/2011 by stefan.wright
Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
myItem.Subject = "QMIS Document Review Needed"


***myItem.Attachments.Add "\\.........\sites\..........\.........\DOCUMENT UPDATE TRACKER\.............xls"***


myItem.Display

Selection.TypeText Text:="Dear User,"
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText Text:="This email is to inform you that you have documents that are currently out of date on QMIS Document Library. These documents could either be on the Quality worksheet or the HS worksheet so please ensure you check both. Please could you view the QMIS Document Updater Spreadsheet to view the documents which you are responsible for, This can be done by clicking the small arrow in the box which says 'Responsible Person' and then selecting your name, if you then do the same in the 'Colour Code' box and select '2' or '3' you will find the documents which should have been reviewed. If you should find that you are listed on a document and this is incorrect then please let me know and if possible advise me of who should be responsible for that document."
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText Text:="The spreadsheet of QMIS updates is attached to this email."
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText Text:="Should you have any further queries regarding this update then please do not hesitate to contact me.    This email will be sent out monthly to those people who have outstanding updates to be completed."
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText Text:="Regards"
End Sub
```

Comment: Error messages for both issues should be shared. What does Outlook complain about?

Comment: Sorry @SliverNinja The error for the hyperlink gives: "Run-time '424': Object Required", The attachment gives: "Run-time error '-2147024843 (80070035)': The operation failed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UNTESTED**

Try this

```
Sub UpdatedQMISReply()
    Dim msg1 As String, msg2 As String
    Dim doc As Object, sel As Object
    Dim Location, Location2

    msg1 = "Please enter the UNC (http://) path for the new file"
    msg2 = "Please enter the QMIS path for the new file"

    Location = InputBox(msg1, "UNC location")
    Location2 = InputBox(msg2, "UNC location")

    Set doc = ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set sel = doc.Application.Selection

    With sel
        .TypeText Text:="Dear User,"
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="This email is to confirm that your recent " & _
                        "file update request to QMIS has now been " & _
                        "completed. I have uploaded all the requested " & _
                        "files and have saved a copy into the archive folder "
        .TypeText Text:="(if an old file existed)."
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="The location on QMIS for the uploaded document is: "

        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range, Address:=Location, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Location2

        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="If your update was concerning a Health & Safety " & _
                        "Document such as a Risk Assessment, or Safe System" & _
                        " of Work, then please note that the naming " & _
                        "convention for these documents is changing, also " & _
                        "the location of the document may change without " & _
                        "prior warning as the QMIS infrastructure is modified."
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="Should you have any further queries regarding " & _
                        "this update then please do not hesitate to contact me"
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="Regards"
    End With
End Sub
```

Alternatively in your actual code, replace

`***ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=Location, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Location2***`

WITH

```
ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Hyperlinks.Add _
Anchor:=ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Range, _
Address:=Location, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Location2
```

Comment: Thanks but I get Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: the set doc line, and if I replace doc on the line after with te stuff from the doc declaration (commenting the line out) I get the same error on the set sel line....

Comment: Ok try this. Comment the line `Set doc...` and `Set sel`. Replace `With sel` with `With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection` Now what happens?

Comment: I get the same result. It gives me the msgbox's I fill them in, and then it stops

Comment: yes, the error 91 error. Sorry I mean that the script stops with the error

Comment: The edited post now works. I still needs to work out why the attachment doesnt work.

Comment: Yes I am. This worked in windows XP with Office 2003 installed though

Comment: You have to copy the file from the network drive to a local folder and then attach it. Once attached, you can delete the file in the local folder. Now try it

Comment: Btw I just tested with a network drive and the code worked just fine. Tested it in Win 7 + OutLook 2010

Comment: I found that the issue is because I was trying to attach a file from Sharepoint (its a really old version that IT wont upgrade). Getting it from a proper network share that isnt sharepoint works. Thanks for the help